# Control event to distinguish designer from runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

The title may be misleading. I have the following

1. A custom user control that extends `Windows.Forms.Control`
2. An `ActiveX` control that is to be nested in the user control

On the `HandleCreated` event of the user control, I am initializing a new instance of the ActiveX control and adding it to the `ControlCollection` of the user control. This leads to the ActiveX control showing up as part of the user control even during the design time. I am looking for a event or a methodology so that the ActiveX control is only initialized at run time and not shown during design time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**DesignMode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) property of the component.

```
if(!DesignMode)
{


}
```